# Как показать элемент на странице после первого скроллинга?

Tags: javascript

Задача такая: нужно показать модалку Клиенту после 15сек от его первого скроллинга?
Реализация на vanilla JS/jquery - особо роли не играет.

Comment: После первого скроллинга ждёте 15 секунд и показываете модалку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function firstScroll(){
    setTimeout(() => console.log('scroll сработал'), 15000);
    document.removeEventListener('scroll',firstScroll);
}

document.addEventListener('scroll',firstScroll);
```

Answer (score 0):

Для тех кому тяжеловат пока JS - ответом на мой вопрос может быть такой код:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    $('.modal-box').show();
  }, 15000);
}
```

});

Comment: Вы на каждое событие скролла поставите таймаут с открытием модального окна.

Comment: после первого срабатывания удалите событие

Comment: Спасибо за коммент. А как это сделать? Или как сделать правильно?